# remove \r\n \" from System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString()

Tags: c#, .net

I fetched email content via GMail Api and converted its Base64 Url encoded string to byte[] and converted to readable html string.
**My goal is to convert the html string to a parsable string without \r \n \"**

```
  var threadText = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(threadBytes);
  threadText = threadText.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
  threadText = threadText.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
  threadText = threadText.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

I have had a look at the value of threadText from GetString()

```
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" name=\"viewport\"/>\r\n
```

the replacing \r \n all work, but the \" doesn't work.

String manipulation is the last thing I would like to do.

Do we have some decent methods to strip these \r \n \" ?

Comment: I think you want `threadText = threadText.Replace("\"", "'")`

Comment: This would replace " not \, wouldn't it? I think OP wants to replace the combination of of the two if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the debugger representation you are seeing / copied from Quick View? In any case, carriage return and linefeed should keep you from parsing otherwise valid html.

Comment: hi @TylerHundley that's correct.

Comment: @Sean I want to replace not only ", but also \.

Comment: @Filburt how can I verify it? I mouse hovered on the theadText and I can still see them.

Comment: Your debugger is inserting the escape characters.  They aren't part of the actual string.

Comment: @RenéVogt "\\"" throws an error. the 1st \ is used to skip \, the 3rd \ is used to skip "

Comment: @Amy  how can I verify it? I mouse hovered on the theadText and I can still see \r \n \".

Comment: Click the hourglass symbol next to it in your debugger to use the string visualizer.  Refer to the debugger documentation for screenshots if needed.

Comment: A good HTML Parser will parse HTML with `\r\n` included. Do not attempt to [Parse HTML using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: thanks @Amy I use the Text Visualizer and can see it does not have \r \n \". So I hope those extra things are inserted by debugger and will not affect my HTML parsing.

Comment: @Franva Again, those won't appear in the Text Visualizer because it is *visualizing* the newline characters.  You see newlines.  You won't see *escaped* newlines.  The newline characters `\r\n` *are* in your string.  Do you understand?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yep, I agree. I do not like the string manipulation.

Comment: @Amy yep, I understood it. thanks

Comment: hi @amy you are correct. I think we should have a answer for this question for the people who have the same issue. If you would like to post a answer, I will accept.